# IO in Haskell not visible

Tags: haskell

I have a little interactive game program. The interactive part looks like this,

```
main :: IO ()
main = playGame newGame
  where

  playGame :: Game -> IO ()
  playGame game = 
    do putStr $ show game
       putStr $ if gameOver game then "Another game? (y or n) > " 
                                 else show (whoseMove game) ++ " to play (row col) > "
       moveWords <- fmap (words . fmap cleanChar ) getLine
       if stopGame game moveWords
         then return ()
         else playGame $ if gameOver game then newGame else makeMove game moveWords
```

This works fine. It displays the game state, asks for the next move, applies that move to the state, displays the new state, etc.

Then I saw a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fk1KzABNm_U) by [Moss Collum](https://stackexchange.com/users/7580/moss-collum) in which he showed a [game](https://github.com/moss/haskell-roguelike-challenge/blob/master/2-i-am-that-merry-wanderer-of-the-night/iatmwotk.hs) that uses the following strategy for interacting with the user.

```
...
userInput <- getContents
foldM_ updateScreen (12, 40) (parseInput userInput) where
...
```

I couldn't find a reference to `foldM_` but assuming it was some sort of `fold` I tried this. (I actually tried a number of things, but this seems clearest.)

```
main' :: IO ()
main' = do
  moveList <- fmap (map words . lines . map cleanChar) getContents 
  let states = scanl makeMove newGame moveList
  foldl (\_ state -> putStr . show $ state) (return ()) states
```

When I run it, I never get the game state printed out until after hitting end-of-file, at which point the correct final game state is printed. Before that, I can enter moves, and they are processed properly (according to the final game state), but I never see the intermediate states. (The idea is that lazy evaluation should print the game states as they become available.)

I'd appreciate help understanding why I don't see the intermediate states and what, if anything, I can do to fix it.

Also, after entering end-of-file (^Z on Windows) the program refuses to play again, saying that the handle has been closed. To play again I have to restart the program. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You fold does not sequence effects (roughly, the M in `foldM`). If you want to use `foldl`, try at least something like `\act state -> act >> putStr ....` so that the previous `act` is indeed run. I would also try using `mapM`, `forM` or their applicative cousins. E.g. try `for_ [1..10] print` after importing `Data.Foldable`

Comment: Check out the haskell tag about section for info on hoogle and other goodies

Comment: Thanks. forM_ does the job. Now, is there a way to re-open <stdin> after entering end-of-file?

Comment: @RussAbbott No, you can't re-open stdin after it's empty. But you can have a move that's only valid once the game ends that resets the game state, or you can automatically reset the game state when the game would otherwise end.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's start with `foldM`:

```
foldM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
```

`a` is the type of things in our container, and `b` is our result type. It takes a `b` (the value we've accumulated so far in our fold`, an`a`(then ext thing in the list`, and returns an `m b`, meaning it returns a `b` and does some monadic actions in the monad `m`.

Then it takes an initial value, a container of `a`'s, and it returns an

This is basically like a normal fold function, but each step of the fold is monadic, and the final result is monadic. So the actions will actually be performed if you use `foldM`.

Now let's look at `foldM_`:

```
foldM_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m ()
```

Source

This is the same, but the final result is `m ()`. This is for the case where we don't care about the final result. We keep the intermediate results and use them to perform monadic actions at each step, but when we finish, we only care about what we did in the monad, so we throw away the result.

In your case, `t` would be `List`, and `m` would be `IO`. So `foldM_` iterates through the list, doing the selected IO actions at each stage, then throws away the final result.

`fold` doesn't actually sequence the actions together, it just folds over your list normally, even if your final result is `IO`. So your `foldl` creates an IO action, namely `putStr . show $ state`, then passes it to the next step of the fold. But, you ignore the first argument of your fold, so it throws the IO away without ever doing anything with it!

This is a tricky thing in Haskell. A value of type `IO Something` doesn't actually do the action when you create it. It just creates an `IO` value, which is just an instruction to the runtime of what to do when it runs main. If you throw it away, and it never gets sequenced into an `IO` that your main performs, then the side-effect will never happen.